# Fetch the String + bounced email correctly

Tags: php, preg-match

I've beeing starting to work with preg_match and for that I've beeing trying to fetch a exactly part of the text with an email on it. However I haven't had success on this task. Bellow is the text and also the preg_match code I've being trying to use.

The Text is this one bellow:

---

> From: testemail@yahoo.de
>   Reply-To:  testemail@yahoo.de
>   To: "fighfo@dihfodf.dfihdofd"

---

What I want to fetch:

---

> To: "fighfo@dihfodf.dfihdofd"

---

And what I've being using so far:

---

> preg_match("/To: \"\b([A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,})\b\"/i",
>   $body, $matches)

---

Please, Does anyone have any idea on how this issue could be solved.

I thank you in advance.

Best regards,

M.J.

Comment: The RegEx appears to be working just fine, so what is the actual issue?

Comment: Somehow I couldn't get the right String "To: " plus the email next to it. But thanks to Danyal I was able to fetch the wright line, and than just work around to get the email after "To: ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can do it like this too:

Read string line by line, if first 3 characters match `To:`, that's that line you are looking for then.

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){
     if($line[0]=='T' && $line[1]=='o' && $line[2]==':'){
       // $line is the line that you are looking for
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Danyal. It has worked like a charm and now I can move on. : )